# Can't successfully change port that Apache2 listens for

Tags: networking, server, apache2

I am trying to change the port that apache listens to from '80' to '8085' (or any other number).

I modified **/etc/apache2/ports.conf** :

```
NameVirtualHost *:8085
Listen 8085
```

And I also modified **/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default** :

```
<VirtualHost *:8085>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
```

The last thing I did was Port Forwarding on my router.  I used to use '80' so I just changed that to '8085'.

Alas, I am unable to reach my apache homepage (the one that says **It Works!** and I am not sure why.  I feel like I have hit all the things that need to be changed.  Any tips?

Also, when i do `netstat -tulpn | grep :8085` i get:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::8085                 :::*                    LISTEN      4232/apache2
```

The port is in RED, is it firewalled?

I have reloaded and restarted apache and the server.

Thank you in advance

EDIT

Output of `iptables -L`

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
fail2ban-apache  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports http,https
fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports 239

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain fail2ban-apache (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain fail2ban-ssh (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Hopefully you can get something out of that.
Additionally, I do not recall what I seen before I made the changes. I am not sure but I think i should be listening for IPv4.  Literally the only things I have changed are what is noted above.

Comment: check the configuration of iptables using `iptables -L`

Comment: @Michael: **Q:** *The port is in RED, is it firewalled?* **A:** No, this is the highlighting of matched strings by `grep`. **Other:** It looks like Apache is listening only on IPv6 socket. Do you need it to be accessible on IPv4? Before the change did you see something like `tcp       0      0 0.0.0.0:80                 0.0.0.0:*                    LISTEN      4232/apache2` in the `netstat` output (i.e. IPv4 socket)?

Comment: Please see edits in main comment.

Comment: @Michael: Your `iptables` do not contain filtering rules. Please test local connectivity to the port 8085: `nc -vvn4 127.0.0.1 8085 </dev/null` the otuput should look like: `Connection to 127.0.0.1 8085 port [tcp/*] succeeded!` Maybe you will need to install the `nc` (netcat) utility: `sudo apt-get install netcat`.

Comment: As I see, he doesn't have apache to listen the `127.0.0.1` but `localhost`. Apache is smart enough that just binds the first `localhost` it finds `::1` instead all instances. Change `Listen 8085` for `Listen 127.0.0.1:8085` and restart the server.

Comment: @Braiam: I do not see `localhost` anywhere except the e-mail address. The Apache should listen on all interfaces. `Listen 127.0.0.1:8085` would not certainly work as Michael want (port forwarding on his router). @Michael: If you discover IPv4 connectivity problem, you can explicitly instruct Apache to listen on IPv4: `Listen 0.0.0.0:8085`

Comment: Pabouk - I ran the `nc -vvn4 127.0.0.1 8085 </dev/null` command and got back exactly what you noted in your post. I will try the IPv4 method after work.

Comment: @pabouk - No luck it seems with the `Listen 0.0.0.0:8085`.  This issue really confuses me.  When I go to the site in my browser it tries to connect for about 10 seconds before throwing an error.  Any other ideas?

Comment: @Michael: So local IPv4 connectivity (to `127.0.0.1`) is OK. Could you please test a connectivity from the local network? Connect another computer to the same LAN as the server (through Ethernet switch on the router or to the same WiFi SSID). Then best is to test both port and HTTP response: `nc -vn4q5 server_IP_addr 8085 <<< $'GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'`. If you get response with HTML code of the initial URL then there is probably problem in port forwarding or filtering on your router.

Answer (score 0):

I do guess that your problem is that you are trying to reach it over IPv4 and it is listening on IPv6.

Sound strange, but does look like it from what you are saying. So why not listen to 8085 on our IPv4 address?

Listen 0.0.0.0:8085

The 0.0.0.0 bein all addresses, if you have mutiple on your system then use the specific address you want instead.

But one question to finish this off, why do you have IPv6 tunred on if you are not using it?

Answer (score -1):

Have you rechecked /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default ? I seem to remember that you edit sites-available rather than sites-enabled, as it's the content of sites-available that gets copied to sites-enabled when you enable a site with a2ensite 
Please see https://forum.linode.com/viewtopic.php?t=7873 especially towards the bottom of the page.  Restarting apache potentially overwrites what is in sites-enabled with what is in sites-available and there should definitely be a 000-default file in sites-available.